# Why do I get Chinese characters when generating random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, random, filewriter

This program generates 50 random numbers between 1 to 100 and the output are written in the fileresult.txt .

```
    FileWriter outputChar = new FileWriter(new File ("fileresult.txt"));
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 50 ; i++){
        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;
        int number = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        outputChar.write(number);
    }
    outputChar.close();
```

The problem is the output are not integer values, but many Chinese characters instead. Why does this happen?

Comment: You're writing raw bytes, if you want ascii integer values use a `PrintStream`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or use `outputChar.write(String.valueOf(number) + "\n");` for minimal rewriting.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch    actually I am doing a comparison between using char-stream and byte-stream .The code above is for the char-stream part.Fyi, I also got the strange characters as the output for the byte-stream part. I hope you can elaborate more on char stream and byte stream and what is their relationship with ascii values and raw byte...It is a bit hard for me to get my head around this concept.

Answer (score 1):

It writes `char`s to the output in the range 1-100, which are UTF-16 chars in the ASCII range of Unicode, but 31 are control codes. `FileWriter` will use the platform default charset to convert from Unicode. My guess it is one of the Big5 Charsets.

```
Path path = Paths.get("fileresult");
try (Writer outputChar = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    // Or UTF_8.
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 50 ; i++){
        int min = 32;
        int max = 127;
        int number = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        outputChar.write(number);
    }
} // Does a close(); even on exception or break/return inside the block.
```

The charset now is made certain to be ASCII.

As the file has no indication what encoding it is in, it still might be shown in the operating system encoding. By not having 31% control codes, Notepad might be smart enough to use ASCII or a superset like Windows Latin-1, Cp1252.

Comment: @lilyniall here's more info on how Notepad takes a guess for encoding https://superuser.com/a/1429229 . Here's the ascii table https://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

The compiler interprets the randomly generated numbers as Unicode and outputs Chinese characters. I would recommend slicing up your code to not generate all integers together or specify the format with `Random().format`.